# OSX moves and renames menu bar created with Qt

Tags: macos, qt, menu

I have a Qt application created under windows, that I am trying to port to mac.

The menu bar contains certain items that, when translated to Mac, were sent to different menu items - and even renamed.

```
A new menu item called the name of the app was created (before the first one, File)
File -> Exit went to AppName -> Exit
Help -> About went to AppName -> About
Tools -> Options went to AppName -> Preferences (!!!!!!!)
```

I don't know how to fix this... the menu was created using Qt Creator, but there is a clear hierarchy in the code for placing the menu items where they are

How can I make mac leave the menu bars where they belong - and not randomly rename them ?

OSX 10.6.8, Qt 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that mac assigns roles to menus that it can recognize by name... So I had to explain that my menus are not the default app menus.

```
#if defined (Q_OS_MACX)
    m_ui->actOptions->setMenuRole(QAction::NoRole);
#endif
```